# Android call OEM activity by component name

Tags: android, adb

On a Huwaie Ascend, when we walk through the settings menu:

```
Settings -> SD card & phone storage -> Software Upgrade -> SD card Upgrade
```

We are then brought to a screen where the user can upgrade.

And then using adb logcat we see this:

```
 Starting activity: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cmp=com.android.settings/.SystemUpgradeCheck }
```

We can use adb to simulate this by calling:

```
adb shell am start -n com.android.settings/.SystemUpgradeCheck
```

This is successful, and we see the screen.

However, when we try to call this from within an activity like this:

```
    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    i.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.android.settings", ".SystemUpgradeCheck"));
    startActivity(i);
```

We get this error:

```
Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.android.settings/.SystemUpgradeCheck}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
```

What can we do to overcome this? Am I calling the intent wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured it out :)

```
Context foreignContext = createPackageContext("com.android.settings", Context.CONTEXT_IGNORE_SECURITY | Context.CONTEXT_INCLUDE_CODE);
Class<?> yourClass = foreignContext.getClassLoader().loadClass("com.android.settings.SystemUpgradeCheck");

Intent intent = new Intent(foreignContext, yourClass);
startActivity(intent);
```